# Applying Hover effect to responsive height image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three column layout. The left and right columns are full background images that I need hover effects for. I couldn't achieve this in CSS so I'm attempting jQuery, but I'm having an issue when it comes to position: absolute on both elements.

It requires I put a height on the image, but I need it to stay responsive. I tried position relative but there is now a noticeable jump when hovering. Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/faumX/4/

Here's an example of my code, 
html:

```
 <div class="one-third">
        <div class="bg-image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/429x900&text=left+up" id="leftUp" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/429x900&text=left+over" id="leftOver" style="display:none;" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.one-third {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:33.332%;
    max-width: 420px;
    position: relative;
    min-height:10px;
    height:auto;
    max-height:900px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.bg-image {
    position: relative;
    min-height:10px;
    height:auto;
    max-height:900px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.bg-image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 420px;
    min-height:10px;
    height:auto;
    max-height:900px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#leftUp {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#leftOver {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

js:

```
$('#leftUp').mouseenter(mouseEnterLeft);
$('#leftOver').mouseleave(mouseLeaveLeft);
var mouseEnterLeft = function(){
    $('#leftUp').fadeOut();
    $('#leftOver').fadeIn();
}
var mouseLeaveLeft = function(){
    $('#leftUp').fadeIn();
    $('#leftOver').fadeOut();
}
```

I'm realtively new to this, if there is a CSS solution to this that is better, I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you just trying to show a different image? do you need the fade?

Comment: Yes it has to fade into a different image of the same exact size.

Comment: I'll post fiddle with example.

Comment: Had the wrong link it should be ok now

Comment: You really don't need to use javascript : take a look at these tutorials using CSS3 http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a few things on your fiddle the problem is when you fade things out they dissapear and opacity is better for this.

I placed the overlay image above the default one and set it to absolute, this way it will be over it but it's hidden on start.

The focus is on the parent div not the image, since it dissapears when you hover it.
Play around with it and see if you can understand what I did, let me know if this is what you were looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#rightUp').mouseenter(mouseEnterRight);
$('#rightOver').mouseleave(mouseLeaveRight);
$('#left').mouseenter(mouseEnterLeft);
$('#left').mouseleave(mouseLeaveLeft);
```

});
var mouseEnterRight = function(){
    $('#rightUp').fadeOut();
    $('#rightOver').fadeIn();
}
var mouseLeaveRight = function(){
    $('#rightUp').fadeIn();
    $('#rightOver').fadeOut();
}
var mouseEnterLeft = function(){
    $('#leftUp').animate({opacity:0});
    $('#leftOver').fadeIn();
}
var mouseLeaveLeft = function(){
    $('#leftUp').animate({opacity:1});
    $('#leftOver').fadeOut();
}

http://jsfiddle.net/faumX/14/

Comment: That's perfect. Great approach, I understand completely. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Thanks, you should however look at Adjit's response and try if you could fix it using transitions.

Javascript is not a bad solution since it covers more browsers but still. You can target a child whilst hovering like div.left:hover img.over {} Good luck